# Showing Dropdown box programatically using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdownbox

I want to show the dropdown box programatically using Twitter boostrap 3.

Following is the piece of code

```
<div class="link-propery">
   <div class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
      <!--
      I don't want to use this for clicking and then showing Dropdown
      <b class="caret"></b>
     -->
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>                         
    </div>
  </div>
```

And when I type this in the console, the dropbox isn't visible:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
```

I want to show the dropdown using programatically and not by clicking some button or link. Is there a way to do this ? Also, I have demoed the same problem using [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vaqon/4/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes the dropdown show programtically:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").trigger("click");
```